# Avoid Bash shell parameter expansion

Tags: bash, shell

I’m trying to create a Bash shell script that gives me the oldest files of n days in a specific folder and optionally indicating a pattern, for example for the file extension, thus giving as input in a single line: the days, the folder and optionally the pattern. It’s relatively simple, I just want to make sure that in this command line I can indicate the pattern without the need for quotes, how do you implement it in the script itself?

I tried the script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Number of days
days=$1

# Directory
directory=$2

# Pattern (optional)
pattern=$3

# Check if the pattern was provided
if [ -z "$pattern" ]
then
  # If no pattern was provided, find all files
  find $directory -type f -mtime +$days
else
  # If a pattern was provided, find files that match the pattern
  find $directory -type f -name "$pattern" -mtime +$days
fi
```

but, if I write as input something like
`./a.sh 20 /home/user/ *.txt`
The * character make it working only if the script folder doesn't contain .txt files...

Comment: enclose your variables in double quotes: `find "$directory*...`!

Comment: Quotes, quotes everywhere. `find "$directory"`, and `./a.sh 20 /home/user "*.txt"`

Comment: http://shellcheck.net/ will flag these problems for you automatically.

Comment: As for the invocation needing to be quoted by the user who's calling the script -- you can't fix that _after the script is started_ because at that point, `*.txt` has already been changed to `a.txt b.txt c.txt`; the fact that that list of words was generated from the original `*.txt` string is something that's never communicated to the child process at all.

Comment: (Separately, `.sh` extensions should be used for shell _libraries_, and only POSIX-compliant shell libraries at that, not executable scripts; see [commandname extensions considered harmful](https://www.talisman.org/~erlkonig/documents/commandname-extensions-considered-harmful/) re: rationale)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but even in a little more complex script like this
`#!/bin/bash

DAYS=$1
DIR=$2
PAT=${3:-'*'}
DEL=${4:-''}
CONF=${5:-''}
FILES=()
while IFS= read -r -d $'\0'; do
   FILES+=("$REPLY")
done < <(find "$DIR" -type f -mtime +"$DAYS" -name "$PAT" -print0)
for FILE in "${FILES[@]}"; do
    echo "$FILE"
if [ "$DEL" = "--delete" ]; then
  if [ "$CONF" = "--confirm" ]; then
           read -p "Sei sicuro" -n 1 -r
           echo
           if [[ $REPLY =~ ^[Ss]$ ]]; then
              rm "$FILE"
           fi
        else
            rm "$FILE"
 fi
fi
done`

Comment: Sorry for my bad English, and being such a noob ^_^
By the way, what i'm trying to do is avoid to write "*.txt" and make that script working reading only *.txt

Comment: The code in the question is correct to use lower-case variable names -- all-caps names are used for variables that reflect or modify shell behavior by POSIX convention. Unfortunately, comment formatting munges code enough that I can't really follow the above beyond that aside to speak more directly to the question at hand.

Answer (score 1):

The shell expands the wildcards even before you scripts starts, so the script doesn't see it as an argument, it sees the names of the files (if there are any).

You either have to quote or escape the argument, or make the script accept a list of files instead. For that, use `shift` to remove the first two parameters from `$@`, and if it's not empty afterwards, it contains the files.